# store mySQL DB inside the application folder

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I would like to develop an application in C# which use the mySQL dbms. I will have to install this software on different pc and all of them will have different records inside their database. Is it possible to store this database in a single file to provide a better mobility or will I have to install the mySQL dbms on all these machines and store the db inside the local server?
If it can't be done,  is there any performant dbms that allows the database to be stored inside a single file?
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can store a whole Innodb database in a single file - but you'll still need to install MySQL on the target machine. For a single user DBMS, this doesn't make a lot of sense. Since you're writing in C# the application will only run on MSWindows machines which would point one towards a JET based approach - but the MDAC legacy has got a bit confused. SQLite looks a lot less painful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, installing a whole server program like mySQL on all the target machines is pointless.
I will definitely try SQLite as it seems enough for my needs and it is also free.